# Which calendar event to consider when user selects same date

Tags: c#, asp.net, calendar, selectionchanged

Am using link button to toggle the calendar.Ive used `calendar.selection_changed` event
to grab the date and i hide the calendar control.But if the user trys to select the same date again what event should i consider to grab the date and change the visibility of calendar.

Thanks
PS: If i use `enable view state` property it works for same date but toggle stops working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

U can Use `Calendar.SelectedDates.Clear();` property in your page_load.
edit: i dnt know abt the events required for it...but this works

Answer (score 0):

The event is raised only if the date selection is changed by user action in the control. For instance, if the user clicks the same date twice, the second click does not raise an event. The event is also not raised if you set a date range programmatically.

Comment: Ya that is my question..do u have any idea about what event will be raised on second click on same selected date?